# Not able to change the Font of UIText View(when using Web Services)

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have one `UItextView`, in my XIB file. I have "set font" size for that of size 28. There's no problem in setting the font size. But When the data comes from the Web services. Am not able to change the `Font` Programatically. I am only able to change the Font when Data has been recieved.
Here's the Idea of the Flow,

1. I took `UItextView` in my xib file
2. I set Its `Font` 28, in XIB only.
3. After receiving the data from Web Services, Its size getting reduce to some what near to     14. I haven't change its font anyway in my Code.

Then I followed this approach

1. I took `UItextView` in my xib file
2. I set Its `Font` 28, in XIB only.
3. And changed Its Font in viewDidLoad too, but same result. The Text size of reducing to font size of 14 after receiving the data from Web Service.

Then I followed Different approach

Changing the `Font` Size of the `TextView` after Receiving data from the Web Services. And Got success. Why the `TextView` font was affected by the data of Web Services? Is there any thing am missing? Or am not able to grasp some kind of Basic? Please explain, If some body faced same kind of problem

Comment: connected `TextView` with `IBOutlet`?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr
yes. It is. Any Idea, why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs normally in nib, Just set the font after setting the text will only the solution.